# URL friendly multi language with htaccess and php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need to create url friendly multi language with htaccess and php, for example:

`mydomain.com/create_account.php`

I need:

English: `mydomain.com/create_account`
Spanish: `mydomain.com/crear_una_cuenta`
Portuguese: `mydomain.com/criar_conta`

Also I will need to make for more files in the same htaccess:

```
mydomain.com/contact_us.php
```

I need:

English: `mydomain.com/contact_us`
Spanish: `mydomain.com/contacto`
Portuguese: `mydomain.com/contato`

```
mydomain.com/login.php
```

I need:

English: `mydomain.com/login`
Spanish: `mydomain.com/login`
Portuguese: `mydomain.com/login`

```
mydomain.com/account.php
```

I need:

English: `mydomain.com/account`
Spanish: `mydomain.com/cuenta`
Portuguese: `mydomain.com/conta`

```
mydomain.com/shopping_cart.php
```

I need:

English: `mydomain.com/shopping_cart`
Spanish: `mydomain.com/mi_carrito`
Portuguese: `mydomain.com/carrinho_de_compras`

```
mydomain.com/checkout.php
```

I need:

English: `mydomain.com/checkout`
Spanish: `mydomain.com/finalizar_compra`
Portuguese: `mydomain.com/finalizar_compra`

Please can you help me to make the htaccess file?

Comment: 1) what have you tried? 2) how are you telling the server which language to serve?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`%{HTTP:Accept-Language}`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond) header condition to check for the browser language:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^create_account /create_account.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteRule ^crear_una_cuenta /create_account.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^pt [NC]
RewriteRule ^criar_conta /create_account.php [L]
```

This way it will rewrite the URL with the appropriate language. You can use the same logic for your other rules.

Or considering you're already using different URLs for each language you could remove those `RewriteCond`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i added in htaccess but does not work, always show page not found error 404.

Comment: I just noticed that I reversed the rules, see updated answer. Note that considering you're using different urls for each language you can skip the rewritecond for this case.

Comment: Thank you so much, now it works only for one language, for the main language, when i change the language and try to access using another language show the error page not found 404.

Answer (score 0):

As recommended in the post i did it and work perfect: Or considering you're already using different URLs for each language you could remove those RewriteCond.

Now the problem is, in the same htaccess:

These rules working fine:
`RewriteRule ^(.*)-ca.html /create_account.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-l.html /login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-pn.html /products_new.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-fp.html /featured_products.php [L]`

But when i added theses rules show page not found:
`RewriteRule ^(.*)-s.html /specials.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-bes.html /best_sellers.php [L]`

Url example:
mydomain.com/specials-s.html Error page not found
mydomain.com/best-sellers-bes.html Error page not found

Thank you.

Comment: Another thing is, if the create_account.php and login.php its in ssl does not work show page not found. Example: https mydomain.com/~user/login-l.html Error page not found and https mydomain.com/~user/create-account-ca.html Error page not found